# NavigationController initWithRootViewController dealloc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, dealloc

I have some pretty simple code where I am using a UINavigationController and adding a rootViewController.  After some processing has occurred I want to pop off the current view controller and replace it with another one.  This seems to work fine, but my original view controller does not dealloc.  I set a breakpoint in it's dealloc and it never gets hit.  Below is my code.  Not sure why happens.  Just for testing if I release startController twice it does go away.

```
StartViewController *startController = [[StartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:startController];
    [nav pushViewController:startController animated:NO];

    self.navController = nav;

    [startController release];
    [nav release];
```

Thanks any help.

Comment: @user665003 : how is your navController property defined ?

Answer (score 1):

Your ultimate goal is to bring the view controller's retain count to zero. So make sure that everything the view retains is released and anywhere the view is retained also release.

Please check the following possible causes:

1. Make sure you pop the view controller from the navController if you have a custom back button. The default Back button will work fine.
2. Make sure that all your IBOutlets are set to nil in viewDidUnload

   ```
   - (void)viewDidUnload 
   {
      [super viewDidUnload];
      self.webView = nil;
   }
   ```
3. If your view is an observer to a model class to receive events

For example

```
model.addObserver(myView);
```

and sure to also do

```
model.removeObserver(myView);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response I really appreciate it. It sent me down another directions which finally led to the solution. I'm a pretty new it iphone dev and it turns out I was trying to pop the rootViewController.  Which I know now you can't do.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though your self.navController has got a holding reference to it. maybe put

```
self.navController =nil;
```

somewhere appropriate, so that when the view has been popped it is released.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to pop off the root view controller.  I instead used the `setViewControllers` message from the `UINavigationController` object to replace all my view controllers.